# Google map not shown/blank using react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am using react-native-maps to show Mapview in my page ,unfortunetely it's working in Iphone but not shown Mapview in android, it only shown logo , and yes I folllowed all the configuration steps as they mention in documentation.

1. Install react-native-maps using:

   ```
   npm install react-native-maps --save
   ```
2. Link maps:

   ```
   react-native link react-native-maps
   ```
3. Check react-native-maps project in `android/settings.gradle`:

   ```
   include ':react-native-maps'
   project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')
   ```
4. Check an dependency of your app in `android/app/build.gradle`:

   ```
   dependencies {
       ...
       compile project(':react-native-maps')
       ...
   }
   ```
5. Check `android/build.gradle`:

   ```
   ext {
       buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
       minSdkVersion = 16
       compileSdkVersion = 27
       targetSdkVersion = 26
       supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
       googlePlayServicesVersion = "11.8.0"
       androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
   }
   ```
6. Specify your Google Maps API Key in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`:

   ```
     <meta-data 
         android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
         android:value="MY API KEY"/>
   ```

This is my `package.json` file dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "accordion-collapse-react-native": "^0.1.6",
    "buffer": "^5.2.1",
    "react": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728",
    "react-native": "0.57.3",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.21.0",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-chooser": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-map-link": "^2.1.6",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.23.0",
    "react-native-maps-directions": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.6.2",
    "react-native-photo-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-popover-tooltip": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-popup-dialog": "^0.15.1",
    "react-native-rating": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-searchable-dropdown": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.0.2",
    "react-navigation": "^2.12.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the meta data tag instead of v2:

```
android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
```

Comment: Thanks,for the reply, but I have a permission issue and i have solved it

Comment: i am also facing same issue . can you please tell me which permission you have added ?

Comment: add 
" <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>"
 in AdroidMenifest.xml